# How do I get one top match for each of the phrases I'm running my query on?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have this query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "myField1": {
              "query": "text1 match1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "myField1": {
              "query": "text2 match2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "myField1": {
              "query": "text3 match3"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I try to run this query this gives me all the docs which match one, two or all three of these. But I only want my query to return top matches, one top match for one match query. Is this possible to do so using elastic search?

For example if this query gets 10 responses, I want it to return only three responses with each of the three responses being the top match for one of the three phrases I have written.

I could do the above thing easily with exact match query, but here the problem is to find best match, not necessarily exact match, because all phrases might not have exact matches.

I tried writing script score functions, I figured out how to get the best match for either of the three phrases (using score mode as 'max'). But I'm not able to figure out a method to get only one response per phrase.

Comment: if I understood, you want the best results for each clausule, right? You must run 3 queries for that.

Comment: Yes that's the issue, I want to do this using one query. Because my search can have 1000s of phrases to match. So it'll not be optimal if I run 1000s queries on elastic search as it will take a lot of time.